# CakePHP3: how to pass parameter to join()?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a `DefaultPermissions` table, so with a  `default permissions` set, and I want to compare this set with a `permissions` set affected to a specific site to see if additionnal default permissions exist.

So I wrote the following query:

```
$defaultPermissions = $this->DefaultPermissions
->find()
->select([
    'user_id' => $selUser->id,
    'role',
    'sequence',
    'product',
    'module',
    'item',
    'value',
    'visible',
    'editable'
])
->join([
    'p' => [
        'table' => 'permissions',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'p.product = DefaultPermissions.product',
            'p.module = DefaultPermissions.module',
            'p.item = DefaultPermissions.item',
            'p.site_id' => $selSite->id   // My problem is here!
        ]
    ]
],
[
    'p.product' => 'varchar', 
    'p.module' => 'varchar', 
    'p.item' => 'varchar',
    'p.site_id' => 'integer'
])
->where([
    'DefaultPermissions.role' => $selUser->role,
    'p.item IS' => NULL, // item doit toujours être présent donc si null, la ligne est absente.
    'OR' => [['DefaultPermissions.product' => $agplan->product->code], ['DefaultPermissions.product' => '']]
])
->all();
```

But despite all `defaultPermissions` can be found for site`selSite->id`, the query gives the complete list existing in `DefaultPermissions` table.
If I remove the line `'p.site_id' => $selSite->id` the list is empty as expected so I conclude that the passed parameter is not well interpreted.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There was just a syntax error in the join:

```
->join([
    'p' => [
        'table' => 'permissions',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'p.product = DefaultPermissions.product',
            'p.module = DefaultPermissions.module',
            'p.item = DefaultPermissions.item',
            'p.site_id = ' => $selSite->id   // '=' was missing
        ]
    ]
],
....
```